# GLSL Refract - what eta value for more dense to less dense transition?

Tags: glsl, glm-math

I'm trying to understand how to use glsl's refract function for ray tracing. Let's say that I have an object with a refractive index of 1.5. If I want to generate a refracted ray, I call `refract(rayDir, surfNorm, 1.0/1.5)` correct?

However, I'd like to know how to handle the resulting transmission ray when it reaches the other side of the object and leaves. What is the `eta` value for this function call? Is it 1.5/1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I'm not highly familiar with this, but since nobody else is answering:

The 3rd argument of `refract()` is documented as "the ratio of indices of refraction eta". So what you're suggesting makes sense to me. It the ratio is `eta` going from material A to material B, the ratio would be `1.0 / eta` going from material B to material A.

Comment: After a little more research, I discovered that the ratio is always the 'source material index of refraction (IOR)' / 'destination material IOR.' So if I'm going from air to glass it's 1.0/1.5 (air IOR/glass IOR). If I'm going from glass to air it's 1.5/1.0 (glass IOR/air IOR).